# Rudin's PMA: Theorem 9.41

Tags: analysis

The previous theorem is needed for $(9.41)$.
[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't understand that how the sufficiently smallness of $h$ and $k$ guarantees that we have $|A-(D_{21}f)(x,y)|$ < $\epsilon$
for all $(x,y)$ $\in$ $Q$.

I Also don't understand from where do we get $(97)$ and how the last inequality implies it .

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the continuity of $D_{21}f$ at $(a,b)$: Given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such, for every point $(x,y)\in E$ that satisfies $|x-a|<\delta$, $|y-b|<\delta$, we have that $|D_{21}f(x,y)-D_{21}f(a,b)|<\epsilon$.  So we have to choose $|h|<\delta$ and $|k|<\delta$. Notice that each $(x,y)\in Q$ satisfies $|x-a|\leq |h|$ and $|y-b|\leq |k|$.